# How to generate legend in leaflet webmap?

Tags: leaflet, legend, web-mapping

Although I have checked the "Create Legend" option in the **qgis2leaf** plugin, it did not generate any legend in the output webmap.

What am I missing here ?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

See their help page (on the help tab in the plugin UI):

> When you're interested in building a legend as well, you need to fill
>   the column legend_exp with a text and legend_ico with the path to an
>   icon which should be shown in the legend for the particular layer.
>   This works only for local layers and non-raster layers. See the
>   example files for details.

Comment: It didn't work out. I've created a column (don't know should it be in a single file or all the layers, but tried both) with all the respective legend texts. But still the same

Comment: Hm. The legend part in the plugin source starts at line 945 https://github.com/Geolicious/qgis2leaf/blob/master/qgis2leaf_exec.py#L945 , maybe you can figure out how to get the legend to work.

Comment: OK. I've figured it out. The legend will not be shown unless there is a proper & valid image path is specified (legend_ico). Now it's working perfectly

Answer (score 2):

you must provide a proper name in the attribute legend_exp and a path to an image of your  choice in legend_ico.

ATM we check whether both columns are there and build the table from what is inside the first column entry:

```
if legend_ico_prov == True and legend_exp_prov == True:
                            iter = i.getFeatures()
                            for feat in iter:
                                fid = feat.id()
                                provider = i.dataProvider()
                                legend_ico_index = provider.fieldNameIndex('legend_ico')
                                legend_exp_index = provider.fieldNameIndex('legend_exp')
                                attribute_map = feat.attributes()
                                legend_icon = attribute_map[legend_ico_index]
                                legend_expression = attribute_map[legend_exp_index]
                                print legend_expression
                                print legend_icon 
                                break
                            legendStart += """<tr><td><img src='""" + unicode(legend_icon) + """'></img></td><td>"""+unicode(legend_expression) + """</td></tr>"""
```